# Doctrine 2 (Symfony) Result set mapping with custom field is always null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm performing the following native query in Symfony 2 repository:

```
$sql = "SELECT f.id, f.title, 'hi' AS custom_field FROM my_feed f";

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping($em);
$rsm->addEntityResult('MedicalCoreBundle:Feed', 'f');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'title', 'title');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'custom_field', 'custom_field');

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

I have created the non-mapped property `custom_field` and its getter and setter `getCustomField` and `setCustomField` in the `Feed` entity.

Mapped fields are hydrated properly but when i add the `custom_field` RSM i get the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: custom_field [...] in symfony\..\AbstractHydrator.php`.

Entity code

```
// non mapped field
private $custom_field;

public function getCustomField()
{
    return $this->custom_field;
}

public function setCustomField($number)
{
    $this->custom_field = (int) $number;

    return $this;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Just a suggestion : What happens if you camelCase your non mapped field as follow `customField` ? (in your entity)

Comment: It does not show the error anymore but the field value is always NULL. it workd if i use `$query->getArrayResult()` though

Comment: add MedicalCoreBundle:Feed entity code

Comment: I added the code. Alwo tried to avoid any camel or underscore (customfield) in entity, query and rsm and use setCustomfield, still get the undefined index error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map `custom_field` or use `addScalarResult` instead of `addFieldResult`

```
...
$rsm->addScalarResult('custom_field', 'custom_field');
...
```

result will look like

```
[
    [0=>entity, 'custom_field'=>custom_field value],
    [0=>entity, 'custom_field'=>custom_field value],
    ...
]
```

Comment: Yes but you have a different data structure at the end and have to hydrate the entity by hand...

Comment: As I know there are now internal tools to hydrate in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Relatvie to your error, you seem to have a **F** instead of **f** in custom_**F**ield somewhere.

Comment: This was a typo. I do have the correct field name. Note that it gets hydrated with query->getArrayResult()